# How to use scrollable-tab-view with react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tabbar

i want use react-native-scrollable-tab-view with react-native-router-flux and so i have created this ScrollableTabView:

```
import React, {
  Component,
} from 'react';
import ScrollableTabView from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import { DefaultRenderer } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import TabBar from './TabBar';

class ScrollableTab extends Component {
  render(){
    const state = this.props.navigationState;

    return (
      <ScrollableTabView renderTabBar={() => <TabBar />} >
        {
          state.children.map(el => {
            return (
              <DefaultRenderer navigationState={el}  key={el.key} {...el} tabLabel={el.title} />
            );
          })
        }
      </ScrollableTabView>
    );
  }
}

export default ScrollableTab;
```

and this TabBar:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated,
  Component
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tab: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  tabs: {
    marginBottom: 70,
    top: 64,
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingTop: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
  },
  tabUnderlineStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#3b5998',
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

const propTypes = {
  goToPage: React.PropTypes.func,
  activeTab: React.PropTypes.number,
  tabs: React.PropTypes.array,
};

class TabBar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.tabs} >
        {this.props.tabs.map((tab, i) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tab} key={tab} onPress={() => this.props.goToPage(i)} >
              <Text>
                {tab}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

TabBar.propTypes = propTypes;

export default TabBar;
```

The result is this:

[image: schermata 2016-05-06 alle 15 35 59]

Why it duplicates the NavBar? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your code here:

```
---> state.children.map(el => {
            return (
              <DefaultRenderer navigationState={el}  key={el.key} {...el} tabLabel={el.title} />
            );
          })
```

state.children probably includes your navbar.  try checking with `console.log(el);` in place of the return. or `console.log(state.children) before the block.  It's hard to say what the problem is without knowing what your props.tabs are, and what your higher order component is.